# How to call postgreSQL count

Tags: python-2.7, postgresql-9.1

How to call postgreSQL count value on program, because select count is show the value , but in my program code to use only count showing an error

```
select
    --poui.id::varchar || '/' || coalesce(poc.id::varchar,'') AS id,
    poui.preorder_id as name,
    poc.start_date as start_date,
    poc.expire_date as end_date,
    poui.state as status,
    select count(*) as no_preorder_completed from preorder_user_input where state = 'done'
    select count(*) as no_preorder_not_completed from preorder_user_input where state in ('draft','confirm')
    count(*) as no_preorder_completed from preorder_user_input where state = 'done'

from
    preorder_user_input poui
left join 
    preorder_config poc on (poui.preorder_id = poc.id)
group by 
    poc.id, poui.id, poui.preorder_id, poc.expire_date, poc.start_date, poui.state
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically if you want a count of some of the rows in PostgreSQL 9.1 you need to use SUM and CASE instead.  I.e.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN mycolumn = desired THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```